# Return powf result to main function C Programming

Tags: c, function, pow

I'm trying to make a separate function that takes parameters x and y from the main function use use it in the powf, assign it to a variable 'result' and output it to the main function. Any help is appreciated

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int  main() {

  float x = 5.5;
  float y = 3;
  float total = 1;
  int i;


  for( i=0; i <= y; i++ ) {
    total = total * x;
  }

  printf("total = %.3f\n",total);
  printf("Result of powf function is: %.3f\n", result);

  return 0;

}

float mathPow(float x, float y){

  result = powf(x,y);

  return result;

}
```

Comment: You don't actually call `mathPow` from `main`. Why?

Comment: Could you clarify what the question is here?

Comment: You need one of the books from the [curated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: You do it in the same way as you call `powf`, except you need to write `float result = powf(x, y);`

Comment: your `for` loop calculates `pow(x, y + 1)`.

Comment: What is the use of `total` here? Plus that loop of yours runs `y+1` times.

Comment: Where is `result` defined? Do you want to use some ancient K&R style imlicite definition?

Comment: Don't you get a load of compiler warnings? If not, compile again with all warnings enabled.

Comment: `for( i=0; i <= y; i++ )` --> `for( i=0; i < y; i++ )`

Comment: I just couldn't see such a newbie mistake by not calling the function in the main and the for loop mistake. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I have modified your code a bit

```
float mathPow(float x, float y){
  float result = powf(x,y);
  return result;
}
int  main() {

  float x = 5.5;
  float y = 3;
  float total = 1;
  int i;
  for( i=0; i <= y; i++ ) {
    total = total * x;
  }
  printf("total = %.3f\n",total);
  printf("Result of powf function is: %.3f\n", mathPow(x,y));
  return 0;
}
```

as you can see you did not called the function `mathPow()` in your `main()`.

In order to execute the **User Define functions** you need to call them from your `main()`

Comment: This code might work, but does not help in any way to describe what the problems were or how this code fixes them.

Comment: @crashmstr thanks to pointing it out i have edited my answer

Comment: Thank you! It was such a newbie mistake by not calling the function in main...

Comment: You are welcome and it's ok we all start at some point

Answer (score 0):

This is the whole program working

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


float mathPow(float x, float y);

int  main() {

  float x = 5.5;
  float y = 3;
  float total = 1;
  int i;


  for( i=0; i < y; i++ ) {
    total = total * x;
  }

  printf("total = %.3f\n",total);
  printf("Result of powf function is: %.3f\n", mathPow(x,y));

  return 0;

}

float mathPow(float x, float y){

 float result = powf(x,y);

  return result;

}
```

Comment: You don't need to post your full code as an answer instead accept an answer which worked for you